# What is the meaning of "who can no longer pause to wonder and stand rapt in awe"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "who can no longer pause to wonder and stand rapt in awe" in the following sentences,

> The most beautiful thing we can experience is the mysterious. It is
>   the source of all true art and all science. He to whom this emotion is
>   a stranger, **who can no longer pause to wonder and stand rapt in
>   awe**, is as good as dead: his eyes are closed. - Albert Einstein

?

Does it mean "he ,who can not pause in order to wonder and who can not stand rapt in respect on the mysterious, is as good as dead. And his eyes are closed(=>And he is dead after he have lived so)" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've understood the meaning of the quote.

It starts out defining the mysterious as the most beautiful thing we can experience. The subject of the next sentence, 'it', also refers to 'the mysterious'.

In the third sentence, 'this emotion', refers to 'experiencing the mysterious'. The phrase, 'who can no longer pause to wonder and stand in awe', describes the subject of the sentence, 'He'. The emotion is a stranger to him. He is as good as dead and his eyes are closed.

Just to be clear, when Einstein writes

> He...is as good as dead

he means that the person is not dead yet, but not being able to experience the mysterious makes him like someone who is dead. He might as well be dead if he can't feel the emotion.

Answer (score 0):

This quote simply says that if a person does not appreciate  the mysterious wonders of science and art ,is better dead than live. So life is a new perception and if one does not have this ability to find true meaning of life .......